# Creating secondary progress bar using multiple clips drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am creating progress bar using imageview with layer list of clip drawable and it is working like a charm. Here is the code:

The xml of background drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/energy_backing" >
        </bitmap>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
            android:drawable="@drawable/energy_full"
            android:gravity="left" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The xml of progress bar:

```
   <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pbEnergyBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/progress_bar_energy2" />
```

And offcourse I can set the progress by calling imageview.setImageLevel(progress).

My question is , how can I add a secondary progress bar like the one in default ProgressBar ?

I thought of adding another clip drawable but then how can I call setLevel twice on two different clips?  any guidance!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another ImageView with the secondary layer list and lay it out exactly on top of the first ImageView...

---

EDIT: Actually, you might be able to use `ProgressBar` with your drawable.

- add another layer to your list with `<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">`
- in `ProgressBar` set `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_energy2"`

See if that works.

Comment: That's a good idea actually. I would rather deal with one view honestly but if I don't get another answer then I will accept yours. Thank you

Comment: added another idea to answer.

Comment: Using progress bar with images does not work properly .. That's why I am using image view. If i user progress bar with images then the image is truncated and not of right size